# Pass a string from Java to Vue.js in an Ionic project

Tags: javascript, java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm building an android app using Ionic & Vue. I'm using inaturalist to authenticate users. Once the user is authenticated by inaturalist, it triggers a callback url in which it sends a code. I'm intercepting the callback code and able to display it in a dialog, but I can't figure out how to pass this on to my vue component.

```
//MainActivity.java
<activity
    android:name=".CallbackActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="myapp"
            android:host="callback" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

//CallbackActivity.java
public class CallbackActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();

        if (data != null && "myapp".equals(data.getScheme()) && "callback".equals(data.getHost())) {
            String codeParam = data.getQueryParameter("code");
            if (codeParam != null) {
                displayReceivedCode(codeParam);
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayReceivedCode(String codeParam) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Received Code");
        builder.setMessage("The code received is: " + codeParam);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                openVueApp(codeParam);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void openVueApp(String codeParam) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("codeParam", codeParam);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); 
    }
}

//Login.vue
async login({commit}:any) {
            const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            
            let authorizationUrl = 'https://www.inaturalist.org/oauth/authorize';
            const responseType = 'code';
            const codeChallengeMethod = 'S256';
        
            commit('SET_LOADING', "Logging in...")
            const codeVerifier = generateCodeVerifier();
            const codeChallenge = await generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
        
            commit('SET_CODE_VERIFIER', codeVerifier)
            
            authorizationUrl += `?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=${responseType}&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=${codeChallengeMethod}`;
            const data = await Browser.open({ url: authorizationUrl });
            console.log(data)
        }
```

Im pretty sure I have to dispatch an event from java and listen for it in my component, but i cant figure out exactly how.

Comment: I hope you develop this for private purposes. I learned to never use Ionic again for business. Trust me, Android is not only Java. It backstabs you everywhere with everything if you are not a pro. If you are developing for private purposes, switch to native Android. This "Ionic one Code Base solution" sounds like the holy grail, but it is not. Just trust me my friend. If it is for business, I wish you much luck. Your best bet is to pass the data with JSON. If you want something like a single code base, create a REST backend with Java, and create a UI for Android and iOS, both in native.

Comment: You will have thousands of problems with your App running an different Android versions. Android is not backwards/forward compatible. There won't be compiler errors, but it will just not work. And the wrapping by Ionic makes this even worse. "But it works ob my machine" you will say...

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error, I've found a solution that works using webView. I'm including it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

On the java side, I've added the following function to CallbackActivity.java

```
//CallbackActivity.java
private void sendCodeToJS(String codeParam) {
    WebView webView = this.getBridge().getWebView();

    webView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.evaluateJavascript("var event = new Event('customCodeEvent'); event.code = '" + codeParam + "'; window.dispatchEvent(event);", null);
        }
    });

}
```

and on the JavaScript side, I have added an event listener to listen for the customCodeEvent

```
// VueComponent.vue
window.addEventListener('customCodeEvent', event => {
    const code = event.code;

    if (code) {
        store.dispatch('auth/exchangeCodeForAccessToken', code);
    }
});
```